# Python multiprocessing not dividing work properly

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to write a simple python script that automatically creates Ethereum private keys in order to get an address with certain numbers.

I have somewhat implemented a script I found online to do this and caused it to loop and check for certain values repeatedly.

I have tried implementing multiprocessing in the code but it seems that not all the cores on my system are being used properly (8 cores 16 threads) as I have diminishing returns when increasing the process count in the pool.

I've also noticed that only 2 cores are being put under load when running the script despite having more than 2 processes.

```
from secrets import token_bytes
from coincurve import PublicKey
from sha3 import keccak_256
from multiprocessing import Pool

def create(i):
    f = open("Success" + str(i) + ".txt", "a")
    while(True):
        private_key = keccak_256(token_bytes(32)).digest()
        public_key = PublicKey.from_valid_secret(private_key).format(compressed=False)[1:]
        addr = keccak_256(public_key).digest()[-20:]
        priv = private_key.hex()
        address = addr.hex()
        if address[:4] == "0000" and address[-4:] == "0000":
            f.write("Private Key: "+ priv + " Address: " + address + "\n")
            print("Proccess " + str(i) + ": Success")
        elif address[:4] == "1234" and address[-4:] == "5678":
            f.write("Private Key: "+ priv + " Address: " + address + "\n")
            print("Proccess " + str(i) + ": Success")
        elif address[:4] == "0002" and address[-4:] == "0002":
            f.write("Private Key: "+ priv + " Address: " + address + "\n")
            print("Proccess " + str(i) + ": Success")
        elif address[:4] == "0000" and address[-4:] == "0002":
            f.write("Private Key: "+ priv + " Address: " + address + "\n")
            print("Proccess " + str(i) + ": Success")
        else:
            print("Proccess " + str(i) + ": Fail")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        pool.map(create, range(4))
```

Any help is appreciated on how I could improve this to get a better performing script. Thanks!

EDIT: Added imports (didn't realize I forgot to copy this lol). Need to install libraries: pysha3, coincurve, web3

Comment: Can you try increasing the `processes=4` to `processes=16` to check if all cores are then used?

Comment: And is the script expected to have constant returns? Could it be that it's natural for the task to get harder to be solved over time? What is `token_bytes`?

Comment: diminishing returns may be the result of bottleneck of writing results to disk. Check your disk activity, and maybe get faster storage? Many small writes may not be as efficient, and be warned that having multiple processes write to the same file is not guaranteed to work in all cases. you may get a jumbled mess if two try to write at the same time (some operating systems prevent this but not all).

Comment: @Aaron - its possible that the disk is the limiting factor, but small writes are okay - they are first cached in the process clib and then when blocks are written out of the process, cashed by the operating system. Each process is using a different file, so that should be okay also.

Comment: @tdelaney maybe I should have said "most operating systems prevent this", but my point stands, I have had very similar scenarios where os was not buffering smartly, so I had to do it myself with a `BytesIO` and write only once I had a few Mb... (on windows,)

Comment: Please make this a fully running script, including imports. To run this, I have to figure out where `keccak_256`, etc... are. Keeping the namespace with more obscure things like keccak can help future readers figure out what you are doing.

Comment: So to address some questions, the script only writes when it finds a matching entry, which is a very very rare occurrence. Also, each process/worker writes to its own file in the case of a matching address. Additionally, I am not exactly sure what token_bytes exactly is, my general understanding of the topic is that it generates some kind of Ethereum wallet private key which then can be decoded into its corresponding address. I do not believe there is any difficulty increase as the script continues to loop. When running with 16 processes, the CPU usage is not spread evenly between cores.

Comment: @selba - I don't see anything wrong with the script. If you add the imports, we can run it ourselves and see what happens.

Comment: @Aaron - I'm not sure how operating systems protect you from writing the same file. Stream writes like what happen here are a process thing - the streaming is handed by clib. By the time you get to the operating system, its block writes to a specific fil offset. If many processes open a shared file for write, the operating system is quite happy to let them overwrite each other.

Comment: @tdelaney I have added the imports

Comment: Also here is an article that I found that contains the actual generation part of the private keys:
https://www.arthurkoziel.com/generating-ethereum-addresses-in-python/

Comment: @tdelaney iirc some os's line buffer input in append mode so things like write to logfile is atomic per line. (windows does not)